# Get value from the datagrid after press button/using datagrid selection changed

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

i have a datagrid that load the data from my database. in my datagrid, i also included the , so that i can checked or unchecked the row.

here is the picture.
[image]

here is my xaml.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="258" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,12" 
              Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="479" ItemsSource="{Binding data}" 
              AlternatingRowBackground="#FFC4B0B0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding nCateogryID}" Header="No." IsReadOnly="True" Width="30" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding sCategoryDesc}" Header="Nama Kategori" IsReadOnly="True" Width="160" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding sCategoryItems}" Header="Keterangan Kategori" IsReadOnly="True" Width="170" />
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Checked?" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

May question is:
How can i know which data already checked whenever i hit the 'Button'? I also do search on google, but found nothing.

i think like this. whenever i click 'Button', i will start to check for each row. how can i do it? any sample for that?

i also think to find another solution, how about using the event handler? thats mean whenever i click for the row and checked, i will trigger the event and check if is it checked or not. How can i do it?

For me, using the event handler is more achieveable because it's much faster rather i have to checked, and press button. lets say if i have only 10 rows, that's not a big problem. How about if i have 1000rows? if i check one by one, it will be troublesome. waste alot of time. any idea? thanks.

Or maybe use the datagrid_selectionchanged.
How can i check the checkbox has been checked or not?

because if we wait until user press button, then we check is checked or not, i think its a slow process. you have to check for each row. if my row only 10rows, maybe its okay. how about if i have 1000 rows need to check? thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<DataGrid.items.count-1;i++)
{
     CheckBox chkBx = (CheckBox)DataGrid.items[i].Cells[3].FindControl("EmpId") ;
     if( chkBx !=null && chkBx.Checked )
      {
        Response.Write(DataGrid.items[i].Cells[1].Text.ToString() );
      }
}
```

Here "EmpId" is checkbox name(control name) and i am using value of first cells for write. You can change the cell index as you want to use.

Comment: hi. thanks for you answer.. but i can't find the "FindControl" statements. and Empld is my header checkbox name?

Comment: hi, i have change the code .Cells[3] was missing between items[i] and FindControl so you was  unabel to find "FindControl" statement. "Empld" is your ItemTemplate control's(checkbox) Id.

Comment: hi.. i already did it with my way. thanks for your answer. i will mark as the correct answer. thanks @Vikash Sinha

Answer (score 0):

In the database you have a field for Checked ? If not, you should extend the class object for your items and add a new property, named IsChecked for example, and then through binding you can check / uncheck the items. In your case "data" is a collection of some custom objects. Extend that custom object and add to it a new property. After this, you can enumerate through the source collection of your datagrid and you can find which ones are checked. Something like this:

```
var checkedItems = data.Where(x => x.IsChecked == true).ToList();
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. don't have. but for the first time i load the data to my datagrid, all row is unchecked. then i can choose which data i want to check. after that i press button and i can get the detail data for each row.